# Selecting text in a WebView?

Tags: android

The browser does this by calling `public void emulateShiftHeld()` method on the WebView which is hidden in the SDK.
Any other options?

Comment: hey you got the solution for your problem?

Comment: this solution doesn't work on ICS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the class that extends *WebView*:

```
public void selectAndCopyText() {
    try {
        Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("emulateShiftHeld", null);
        m.invoke(this, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // fallback
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,
             KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(this);
    }
}
```

And then you have to use *ClipboardManager* to watch for new text.

Works on Android 1.5 - 2.3. [emulateShiftHeld()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#emulateShiftHeld()) made public since 2.2.

Comment: As long as the user "cooperates" by **manually** selecting the text. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250290/why-doesnt-this-motionevent-simulation-work

Comment: Under Anroid 4.0.3 m.invoke(webView, null) cause native crash 09-21 23:20:49.151: A/libc(4103): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000014 (code=1)

Comment: Sorry I don't get this.. I've added selectAndCopyText() in my class that extends WebView, but where do I call this function to allow text in WebView to be selectable?

Answer (score 3):

This chunk of code does the exact same thing as emulateshiftheld().  It allows the user to select text. Then automatically copies it to the clipboard.

```
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,
                 KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
            shiftPressEvent.dispatch(portal);
```