# How to get text selected before user clicks on Copy

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-3.1-honeycomb

I have a WebView and I want user to be able to select text and then display a QuickAction so that they can choose the action he will perform on that text he just selected.

The problem I have is that I can't find a way to get text selected before the user clicks on Copy on the Action Bar.

[image: Example of text selection with Action Bar]

I want to popup the QuickAction as soon as TouchUp event is fired and I don't want to have them to select Copy on the Action Bar before that.

Any idea on how to implement this behaviour?

I'm developping on Android 3.1 SDK and using android.content.ClipboardManager.

Comment: Thanks Justin for correcting my bad english

Comment: Anybody sort this out?  Need the same (ish).

Comment: Take a look of this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111844/selecting-text-in-a-webview