# Android Text Selection In Webview

Tags: android, webview, clipboard

I am using webview for displaying content in Android Honeycomb(3.x). I created customized action menu for cut,copy and paste.How can i copy the selected text in Webview by using my customized action menu.

Comment: this could be of help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111844/selecting-text-in-a-webview

Comment: Did  the answer help you? Then please accept it. If not, please explain what does not work yet.

Answer (score 8):

May It Will Help...

```
public void selectAndCopyText() {
try {
    Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("emulateShiftHeld", null);
    m.invoke(this, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // fallback
    KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,
         KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
    shiftPressEvent.dispatch(this);
}
```

}

Got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1113204/638987

Comment: It works on Android 3.2! Some others answers suggested boolean parameter in emulateShiftHeld --- it is not correct! Use "null" as in code above and it will work for you!

Comment: Under Anroid 4.0.3 m.invoke(webView, null) cause native crash `09-21 23:20:49.151: A/libc(4103): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000014 (code=1)`.

Answer (score -2):

Try below code...

```
private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view)
{
    try
    {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);
        Toast.makeText(this, "select_text_now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
    }
}
```

and Call above method wherever you want...

```
emulateShiftHeld(mWebView);
```

for more details see this... [Android: how to select texts from webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview)

Comment: This is code for Android 2.2. Surej published code which works for both Android 2.2 & 3.2, but this is still problem for Android 4.* (Ice Cream Sandwich). The code above just do nothing under Ice Cream Sandwich.